# Python subprocess - Run shell command and do something on specific command output

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am writing a python script for automation.

I need to run a linux shell command (Program: `dvbv5-zap`) and wait for specific command output (`DVR interface '/dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0' can now be opened`). When command outputs this string python should run another shell program.

I don't know how to capture subprocess cli output, I tried with `.stdout.readline()`, and I got nothing.
I run a command with `subprocess.Popen(['dvbv5-zap', 'args'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2013/10/11/catching-string-from-stdout-with-python/

Code snippet:

```
# Imports
import os, sys, subprocess

# Build command
command = [ 'python', os.join.path('/path/to', 'scriptFile.py') ]

# Execute command
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

# Read stdout and print each new line
sys.stdout.flush()
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):

    # Print line
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(">>> " + line.rstrip())


    # Look for the string 'Render done' in the stdout output
    if 'Render done' in line.rstrip():

        # Write something to stdout
        sys.stdout.write('Nice job on completing the render, I am executing myFunction()\n' )
        sys.stdout.flush()

        # Execute something
        myFunction()
```